# Obtain screen status using ADB

Tags: android, adb

I need to know in my script whether or not the device's screen is off. Is there any simple command to obtain such information using ADB?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`dumpsys power | grep mScreenOn`

Comment: Is this specific to some range of devices or Android specific? It works, but better is to grep for mScreenOn= (mScreenOn returns more than one entry in my case).

Comment: This command works on 4.2+ devices, use `dumpsys input_method | grep mScreenOn` for devices with a lower version. For more info see my answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21419347/1345115

Comment: Just a note, dumpsys is a shell command, not an adb command. The cut and paste answer would be adb shell dumpsys power | grep mScreenOn

Comment: Doesn't work with me (Android 6). This only shows if the graphical data is on or off. If I connect with adb to the phone and turn the screen off, this still shows as the screen being on.

Answer (score 12):

On 5.0 it looks like you have to grep the `dumpsys power` output for

```
Display Power: state=OFF
```

or

```
Display Power: state=ON
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
adb shell dumpsys display | grep mScreenState
```

Output:

```
mScreenState=OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

On Moto G5+, Moto X4, and Samsung Note 8 I'm seeing the following to work whereas dumpsys power did not (all devices are Marshmallow or later):

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle | grep mScreenOn
```

yields,

```
mScreenOn=false
```

when the screen is 'locked' whether blank or not, whereas,

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep mScreenOn
```

yeilds,

```
mScreenOnEarly=false mScreenOnFully=false
```

only if the screen is not 'breathing' info such as the time.

Use dumpsys deviceidle to know if the screen needs to be unlocked to allow user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

- My Phone: `XiaoMi 9`

  - Android: `10`

## use adb to check screen status ON/OFF ?

### method 1: use `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker`
- Output:

  - `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker=false` -> Screen **OFF**
  - `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker=true` -> Screen **ON**

### method 2: use `mWakefulness`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mWakefulness=`
- Output:

  - `mWakefulness=Dozing` -> Screen **OFF**
  - `mWakefulness=Awake` -> Screen **ON**

### method 3: use `nfc` (if android has NFC module)

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep mScreenState=`
- Output:

  - `mScreenState=OFF_LOCKED` -> Screen **OFF** (and Locked)
  - `mScreenState=ON_XXX` -> Screen **ON**

    - `mScreenState=ON_LOCKED` -> Screen ON (and **Locked**)
    - `mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED` -> Screen ON (and **Unlocked**)

### method 4: use `service call`

- Command: `adb shell service call power 12`
- Output:

  - `Result: Parcel(00000000 00000000   '........')` -> `0` means Screen **OFF**
  - `Result: Parcel(00000000 00000001   '........')` -> `1` means Screen **ON**