# How to tell if screen is on with ADB

Tags: android, testing, adb, monkeyrunner

I am looking to find out whether or not it is possible to determine if the screen is on on an android device using ADB. I need to know this for some tests I am trying to run using monkey runner. Is there a shell command I can enter, and thus include as part of a monkey runner command, that will tell me definitively if the screen is on or off?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19612157/1778421

Comment: @AlexP. Yeah it is, I missed that while looking for this answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In doing some testing I've found that using `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mScreenOn` will work on devices that have a version number of 4.2+

The command that I have found to work on all devices I have tested so far is to use:

```
 adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mScreenOn
```

which will produce something like:

```
mSystemReady=true mScreenOn=true
```

which you can use to determine if the screen is on.

Tested on all Android Emulators in the range 2.2 - 4.4.2, Samsung Galaxy SII (4.0.4), Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 (4.0.4), and Nexus 4 with CM11

Also worth mentioning, on pre 4.2 devices you can use the command `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mPowerState` to get something like this:

```
mIsPowered=true mPowerState=3 mScreenOffTime=24970 ms
mPowerState=SCREEN_BRIGHT_BIT SCREEN_ON_BIT
```

and detect if the SCREEN_ON_BIT string is present

Comment: On Lollipop (Nexus 6), the first command responds with `mInteractive=true` when the screen is on, or `mInteractive=false` when off; and the second command responds with `Display Power: state=ON` when on, and `state=OFF` when the screen is off.

Comment: On my Sony Bravia Android 8 TV, `dumpsys power` has no `mScreenOn`. But I see `mWakefulness=Asleep` when the TV screen is off, `mWakefulness=Awake` when the TV screen is on.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you enter:

```
 adb shell dumpsys power | grep mScreenOn
```

This will return a true or false value telling you whether or not the screen is currently on. It should look like this:

```
mScreenOn=true
```

Knowing this, all you need to do is parse the true/false value out of the result, and feed the shell command into a monkey runner script.

This was tested on an android device running 4.4.2.

Comment: The service to dump may vary depending on the device you are using. On my Nexus 4 emulator I needed to dump input_method instead of power.

Comment: @CarloB. That is also good to know, I have a physical Nexus 4 and 5 both running 4.4.2, both will respond to dumpsys power. I'm curious if your command is specific to the emulator, or a specific version of android.