# How to verify android device Screen ON or OFF using adb shell command

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat, android-9.0-pie

Tried to check device Screen ON or OFF using `mScreenOn=true` or `mPowerState=SCREEN_BRIGHT_BIT`. But the following commands are NOT working in latest android versions. It is returning nothing

Following commands working fine in Android - 4.3 Jelly Bean

1. using input_method dumpsys

   `adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mScreenOn`
2. using power dumpsys

   `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mScreenOn`
                        or

   `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mPowerState`

is there any other way to verify the screen OFF or ON state using adb shell command on latest android versions (Lollipop, Nougat, Oreo, Pie,..etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently I had same problem and found out below solution.

mInteractive value would be "true" in dumpsys input_method for display ON and "false" for display OFF.

**Ex usage in shell script:**

```
screen_info=`adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep mInteractive=true`
if [[ $screen_info == *"mInteractive"* ]]
then
    echo "Screen is ON"
     #Do something
else
    echo "Screen is OFF"
    #Do something
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

has answer for [android - Obtain screen status using ADB - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611945/obtain-screen-status-using-adb/60037598#60037598), and copy to here:

- My Phone: `XiaoMi 9`

  - Android: `10`

## use adb to check screen status ON/OFF ?

### method 1: use `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker`
- Output:

  - `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker=false` -> Screen **OFF**
  - `mHoldingDisplaySuspendBlocker=true` -> Screen **ON**

### method 2: use `mWakefulness`

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys power | grep mWakefulness=`
- Output:

  - `mWakefulness=Dozing` -> Screen **OFF**
  - `mWakefulness=Awake` -> Screen **ON**

### method 3: use `nfc` (if android has NFC module)

- Command: `adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep mScreenState=`
- Output:

  - `mScreenState=OFF_LOCKED` -> Screen **OFF** (and Locked)
  - `mScreenState=ON_XXX` -> Screen **ON**

    - `mScreenState=ON_LOCKED` -> Screen ON (and **Locked**)
    - `mScreenState=ON_UNLOCKED` -> Screen ON (and **Unlocked**)

### method 4: use `service call`

- Command: `adb shell service call power 12`
- Output:

  - `Result: Parcel(00000000 00000000   '........')` -> `0` means Screen **OFF**
  - `Result: Parcel(00000000 00000001   '........')` -> `1` means Screen **ON**

Answer (score 3):

Android 5.0.1 – Lollipop the behavior changed, they removed logging mScreenOn

Tried many times and found out after comparing the dumpsys  input_method files

```
adb shell dumpsys input_method | grep -i mActive
```

Answer (score 0):

NFC API give you some option to know if the screen ON or OFF and is locked or not, in my side i use the adb shell command which return screen state :

```
adb shell dumpsys nfc | grep -e 'mScreenState=' -e 'Screen State:' | tr : = | cut -d '=' -f2
```

Return: **ON_LOCKED** or **OFF_LOCKED** or **ON_UNLOCKED** or **OFF_UNLOCKED**

Note:
Some device have mScreenState params (like pixel device) and other have Screen State params (like Galaxy Tab)